# C - bmp images, rotating, fliping and enlarging

Tags: c, bmp, flip

I am currently doing a C program where I need to rotate, flip and enlarge an bmp image. All of my three methods work correctly by themselves, but when I try to perform two or more they will overwrite the previous action. Ex if I want to rotate and then flip the image, only flip is showing on the result.

This is an example of my flip :

```
int flip (PIXEL *original, PIXEL **new, int rows, int cols)
{
    int row, col;

     if ((rows <= 0) || (cols <= 0)) return -1;

     *new = (PIXEL*)malloc(rows*cols*sizeof(PIXEL));

     for (row=0; row < rows; row++)
     for (col=0; col < cols; col++) {
     PIXEL* o = original + row*cols + col;
     PIXEL* n = (*new) + row*cols + (cols-1-col);
     *n = *o;
     }

     return 0;   }
```

and then in the main works like this:

```
 readFile(inputFile, &rw, &cl, &b);
if(scale != 0)
{
    enlarge(b, rw, cl, scale, &nb, &rw, &cl);
}
if(degree != 0)
{
    rotate(b, rw, cl, degree, &nb, &rw, &cl);
}
if(fflag == 1)
{
    flip(b, &nb, rw, cl);
}
```

writeFile(outputFile, rw, cl, nb);

Comment: The original data read is under `b`, the data modified is returned under `nb`. But you always again pass in to the modifier functions `b`, never `nb`.

Comment: each activity needs to use the latest modified version of the image, NOT reference the original version